# magento render certain blocks in a static block

Tags: magento-ee

This works in a **CMS** page but I need to render this block in a **static block**:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="37"  template="tm/quickbuy/catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

The block above is very similar except with different directory paths to the one below. When i insert the one below it works. The one above does not work.

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

- I've made sure they are whitelisted.
- I've tried to change directories by putting the top block in the same
  directory as the bottom block.

Any idea to why my first block does not render properly?